# Why doesn't scala.collection.Map have sort methods?

Tags: scala

Is there any particular reason why one has to convert a `Map` to a `Seq` in order to sort by keys or values. Why hasn't Scala included sort methods(e.g. `sortBy`,`sortWith`,`sortByKey`,`sortByValue`) in the `Map` API? Even the `SortedMap` or `TreeMap` constructors need sequences to operate on. So programmatically:

```
val m = Map("01" -> List(34,12,14,23), "11" -> List(22,11,34))
m.toSeq.sortBy(_._1) // this is the way to go
m.sortBy(_._1) // why couldn't this also be the way to go?
```

Map consumers already work with tuples

```
m.foreach {
   entry: (String, List[Int]) => println(s"key:${entry._1},value:${entry._2}")
}
```

Comment: Maps are unordered collections. You can not sort something that doesn't have an order.

Comment: I'm afraid this is too generic since `SortedMap` and `TreeMap` are `Map`s but are ordered collections. Even so, you can still order entries of a generic `Map` as well (after having converted it to a `Seq`). Maybe you meant to articulate your thoughts in a different way. Thanks anyway.

Comment: **Seqs** are a kind og collection that guarantees order, always. The first element goes first, the second element goes second, etc _(this applies to lists, vectors, streams, anything that is a sequence)_. **Maps**, on the other hand, doesn't guarantee order. There are special kinds of maps that guarantee order of keys, and there are some other special kind of maps that guarantee order of insertion. But the **Map** trait / type / kind doesn't. So it can not guarantee order and such, it may not be sorted _(especially for any given predicate)_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keeping the keys sorted puts a constraint on the possible implementation of a `Map` which would make it less efficient in the general case. That is why the order of the keys is implementation-dependent, and why there is a separated `SortedMap` type that does keep the keys sorted if required.

It would be possible for `Map.sortBy` etc. to return a `SortedMap` but that would not be consistent with the equivalent methods on other collection types.

The way this is typically done is to have a separate list of sorted keys and then use that to iterate over the `Map`.

Comment: or instead of a separate list, perhaps a definition of ordering which one can apply to the keys when iterating?

Comment: Still, from what I can see, no extension of `SortedMap` has a sort method. So I guess one cannot dictate the way in which the map entries will be ordered while being inserted 
 - even in an order-oriented `Map` implementation.But I guess efficiency is good enough a reason...

Comment: @Niko a **SortedMap** sorts by their keys. So it doen't makes sense to add `sort` like methods. It is always sorted by the keys, you can not say sort by values or other things.

Comment: I think Luis is just trying to be helpful and thorough. `SortedMap.from` takes `Ordering[K]` for easy re-shuffle, still key-based.

Comment: One use case is to iterate but apply a new ordering to subranges. I see you can use span recursively for that, but it produces intermediate maps. Maybe it would be called `groupFlatMap`.

Answer (score 0):

`sortBy` returns the same collection type, which is a Map in your case, so you cannot do sortBy because Map is unordered. Therefore a conversion to other collection type is needed (in this case, to `SortedMap`):

```
val m = Map("01" -> List(34,12,14,23), "11" -> List(22,11,34))
implicit val mOrd: Ordering[String] = (s1, s2) => s1.toInt - s2.toInt
m.to(SortedMap) //return: TreeMap(01 -> List(34, 12, 14, 23), 11 -> List(22, 11, 34))
```

Note that this `Ordering[String]` will override all the ordering for String in the same scope. You can also pass it explicitly as a parameter, but it is slight more verbose:

```
val m = Map("01" -> List(34,12,14,23), "11" -> List(22,11,34))
m.to(SortedMap.sortedMapFactory(((s1,s2) => s1.toInt - s2.toInt): Ordering[String]))
```